# Alter MySQL table with PDO and prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, alter-table

I've used PDO in my project with PHP and MySQL. Everything is working fine, but I have an error on executing the code below:

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE tbl_invoices AUTO_INCREMENT = ?";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($invoice_start));
```

I want to alter a table with PDO prepared statement. But I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line ...

I tested different solutions, but none of them could not solve it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: you can't bind that way

Comment: Can't do it for all alter commands?

Answer (score 2):

> `ALTER TABLE tbl_invoices AUTO_INCREMENT = ?`

This is what you are doing wrong thin first place.

## Never. Ever. Touch. The auto increment.

Any time you take it as a number, it means a **severe** flaw in the database design.

While regarding altering tables in general - yes, most of time you cannot bind.

Comment: Since we should "never ever touch the auto increment", is it a horrible idea to use the AI field for order? E.G was this row inserted before this one?

Comment: 1) `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will inflate the auto increment value when the record exists.  The ability to prevent large gaps being created in the auto-increment can be nice.
2) MySQL and MariaDB prevent you from setting it to a value lower than the maximum.
3) If you want to ensure no values below a specific value are created (for example, if you want to later import data that you know has a maximum ID) it is also useful to set the AUTO_INCREMENT id.